# Assigning the correct ID to a form?

Tags: python, django

So I'm expanding on the official tutorial, and I'm trying to let a user create their own poll. I'm having trouble assigning the correct question_id to the choice, so the choice aligns in the database with the question and both can be read off. Here is my view:

```
def poll_create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        Qform = QuestionForm(request.POST)
        Cform = ChoiceForm(request.POST)
        if Qform.is_valid():
            poll = Qform.save(commit=False)
            poll.author = request.user
            poll.pub_date = timezone.now()
            poll.save()
            if Cform.is_valid():
                poll = Cform.save(commit=False)
                poll.author = request.user
                findid = Question.objects.all().order_by("-id")[0] ##Finds the id of the last question in database
                poll.question_id = findid.id + 1
                poll.save()
                return redirect('polls:detail', pk=poll.pk)
    else:
        Qform = QuestionForm()
        Cform = ChoiceForm()
    return render(request, 'polls/create.html', {'Qform': Qform, 'Cform': Cform})
```

So the idea is to have a question form (Qform) which writes the question to the database, and then below on the webpage a choice form (Cform), which writes the answer to the database. I'm really confused about applying a question_id to the Cform. At the moment, I have this line:

```
findid = Question.objects.all().order_by("-id")[0] ##Finds the id of the last question in database
poll.question_id = findid.id + 1
```

Which seems like a very hacky attempt to find the last id and assign it to the next one. It doesnt line up because the poll.pk has a different value. I'm at a loss here and don't really understand what's going on. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for `Question.objects.latest()`? Otherwise the id should be auto assigned by default when you create a question if that's what you mean

Comment: It is assigned to the question, but say I delete the findid line, I still need to apply the question_id to the Choiceform, else I get this error: NOT NULL constraint failed: polls_choice.question_id.

Comment: When using 'poll.id', we still get the error: NOT NULL constraint failed: polls_choice.question_id. I'm not sure why though, that's the puzzling bit

Comment: Did you implemented Sayse's suggestion ? Because _.latest()_  will give you the last entry created, which you questioned for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a bit confusing because you are using the variable `poll` for questions and choices. It would be better to use `question` and `choice` instead.

You should check that *both* forms are valid before you start saving, otherwise you can end up with a question without a choice if the question form is valid but the choice form is invalid.

After you have saved the question, you can get the id with `question.id`, and you can assign the question to the `choice` object. There is no need to do a query to find the latest question id.

Putting that together, you have something like:

```
if Qform.is_valid() and Cform.is_valid():
    question = Qform.save(commit=False)
    question.author = request.user
    question.pub_date = timezone.now()
    question.save()
    choice = Cform.save(commit=False)
    choice.author = request.user
    choice.question = question
    choice.save()
    return redirect('polls:detail', pk=question.pk)
```

Note also  that it's recommended to use lowercase `question_form` and `choice_form`, for the form instances, and uppercase `QuestionForm` and `ChoiceForm` for the classes.

Comment: Oh wow, it worked! Thankyou so much! Does the line 'choice.question = question' automatically assign the same id number to the choice?

Comment: Yes, with foreign keys, you can assign the object with `choice.question = question`, or the id with `choice.question_id = question.id`. Note that this works because we have already called `question.save()`, which sets `question.id`.